# GDPR Compliance Sufficiency for Google Family Products

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, adsense

Since [the "non-specific" question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50815510/753531) I asked earlier didn't have the repercussion nor the closure I was expecting and needed, I decided to move on with the implementation I left there and perpetuate the user decision regarding the use of cookies through a cookie, even though this is as stupid as it sounds.

I'll favour the general laziness around replicating the fully functional, yet not exactly useful, HTML of the other topic in here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <title>GDPR Compliance Implementation</title>

        <style stype="text/css">

        html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font:inherit;font-size:100%;vertical-align:baseline}html,body{color:#242729;font-family:Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;line-height:1.26666667}body{background:#FFF;box-sizing:border-box;color:#242729;display:flex;flex-direction:column;font-family:Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;line-height:1.30769231;min-height:100%;min-width:1075px}a,.s-link{color:#07C;cursor:pointer;text-decoration:none}a.s-link__inherit,.s-link.s-link__inherit{color:inherit}.td-underline{text-decoration:underline!important}div{display:block}p{clear:both;margin-bottom:1em;margin-top:0}input[type="submit"],input[type="button"],button,.button,.btn,[class*="btn-"],.hero-box.double-panel .panel.white .btn{background-color:transparent;border:1px solid transparent;border-radius:2px;box-sizing:border-box;cursor:pointer;display:inline-block;font-family:inherit;font-weight:400;line-height:1;min-height:2.46153846em;outline:none;padding:.61538462em 1em;position:relative;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;touch-action:manipulation;transition:color .1s ease-in,background-color .1s ease-in,border-color .1s ease-in,box-shadow .1s ease-in;vertical-align:middle}svg:not(:root),symbol,image,marker,pattern,foreignObject{overflow:hidden}svg{width:14px;height:14px}.svg-icon{vertical-align:bottom;-moz-transform:rotate(360deg)}.s-btn .svg-icon{transition:opacity 200ms cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1);margin:-.30769231em .15384615em -.15384615em -.53846154em}select,input,button,.button,a.button:link,.btn,[class*="btn-"],.hero-box.double-panel .panel.white .btn{background-color:#0095ff;border-color:#07c;box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 #66bfff;color:#FFF}.svg-icon:not(.native) *{fill:currentColor}.s-btn{background-color:transparent;border:1px solid transparent;border-color:rgba(0,89,153,0);border-radius:2px;box-shadow:0 0 0 0 rgba(0,149,255,0);color:#07C;cursor:pointer;font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:400;line-height:1.15384615;outline:none;padding:.8rem;position:relative}.s-btn,.s-btn:focus{background-color:rgba(0,119,204,0)}.s-btn,.s-btn:hover,.s-btn:focus,.s-btn.is-selected,.s-btn[disabled]{background-image:none}.s-btn__inverted{box-shadow:0 0 0 0 rgba(0,149,255,0);color:rgba(204,234,255,0.9)}.s-btn__inverted,.s-btn__inverted:focus{background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0)}.bg-black-700{background-color:#3b4045!important}.fc-white{color:#FFF!important}.baw0{border-width:0}.lh-lg{line-height:1.61538462!important}.ps-fixed{position:fixed}.r0{right:0}.b0{bottom:0!important}.l0{left:0}.grid{display:flex}.grid-center{align-items:center!important;justify-content:center!important}.p16{padding:16px!important}.gs8{margin:-4px}.mx-auto{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}.m0{margin:0}.mb-0{margin-bottom:0!important}.mt-10p{margin-top:10%}.ml-auto{margin-left:auto}.gsx,.gsx>.grid,.gsx>[class*="grid--cell"]{margin-bottom:0;margin-top:0}.gs8>.grid,.gs8>.grid--cell{margin:4px}.wmx10{max-width:81.025641rem!important}.z-banner{z-index:5000!important}.hidden{display:none!important}

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="mx-auto mt-10p">
            <p>GDPR Compliance Implementation</p>
            <p>
                Have you agree with GDPR Compliance?
                <span id="hasCompliedWith">NO</span>
            </p>
            <p id="disagreeWithGDPR">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Click here</a> to disagree with GDPR
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id="js-gdpr-consent-banner" class="p16 bg-black-700 fc-white ps-fixed b0 l0 r0 z-banner" role="banner" aria-hidden="false">
            <div class="wmx10 mx-auto grid grid__center jc-spacebetween gs8 gsx" role="alertdialog" aria-describedby="notice-message">
                <div class="grid--cell" aria-label="notice-message">
                    <p class="mb0 lh-lg">
                        This site uses cookies to deliver our services and to show you relevant ads and job listings.
    By using our site, you acknowledge that you have read and understand our <a class="s-link s-link__inherit td-underline fc-white" target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com/legal/cookie-policy">Cookie Policy</a>, <a class="s-link s-link__inherit td-underline fc-white" target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy">Privacy Policy</a>, and our <a class="s-link s-link__inherit td-underline fc-white" target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public">Terms of Service</a>.
    Your use of Stack Overflow’s Products and Services, including the Stack Overflow Network, is subject to these policies and terms.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="grid--cell ml-auto" aria-label="notice-dismiss">
                    <button class="s-btn s-btn__inverted fc-white bg-black-700 baw0 p16 js-notice-close" role="status" aria-hidden="true">
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" id="gdpr" class="svg-icon m0 iconClearSm" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 14 14">
                            <path d="M12 3.41L10.59 2 7 5.59 3.41 2 2 3.41 5.59 7 2 10.59 3.41 12 7 8.41 10.59 12 12 10.59 8.41 7z"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            /*!
             * JavaScript Cookie v2.2.0
             * https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie
             *
             * Copyright 2006, 2015 Klaus Hartl & Fagner Brack
             * Released under the MIT license
             */
            !function(e){var n;if("function"==typeof define&&define.amd&&(define(e),n=!0),"object"==typeof exports&&(module.exports=e(),n=!0),!n){var t=window.Cookies,o=window.Cookies=e();o.noConflict=function(){return window.Cookies=t,o}}}(function(){function g(){for(var e=0,n={};e<arguments.length;e++){var t=arguments[e];for(var o in t)n[o]=t[o]}return n}return function e(l){function C(e,n,t){if("undefined"!=typeof document){if(1<arguments.length){"number"==typeof(t=g({path:"/"},C.defaults,t)).expires&&(t.expires=new Date(1*new Date+864e5*t.expires)),t.expires=t.expires?t.expires.toUTCString():"";try{var o=JSON.stringify(n);/^[\{\[]/.test(o)&&(n=o)}catch(e){}n=l.write?l.write(n,e):encodeURIComponent(String(n)).replace(/%(23|24|26|2B|3A|3C|3E|3D|2F|3F|40|5B|5D|5E|60|7B|7D|7C)/g,decodeURIComponent),e=encodeURIComponent(String(e)).replace(/%(23|24|26|2B|5E|60|7C)/g,decodeURIComponent).replace(/[\(\)]/g,escape);var r="";for(var i in t)t[i]&&(r+="; "+i,!0!==t[i]&&(r+="="+t[i].split(";")[0]));return document.cookie=e+"="+n+r}for(var c={},f=function(e){return e.replace(/(%[0-9A-Z]{2})+/g,decodeURIComponent)},a=document.cookie?document.cookie.split("; "):[],u=0;u<a.length;u++){var s=a[u].split("="),p=s.slice(1).join("=");this.json||'"'!==p.charAt(0)||(p=p.slice(1,-1));try{var d=f(s[0]);if(p=(l.read||l)(p,d)||f(p),this.json)try{p=JSON.parse(p)}catch(e){}if(c[d]=p,e===d)break}catch(e){}}return e?c[e]:c}}return(C.set=C).get=function(e){return C.call(C,e)},C.getJSON=function(e){return C.call({json:!0},e)},C.remove=function(e,n){C(e,"",g(n,{expires:-1}))},C.defaults={},C.withConverter=e,C}(function(){})});

            window.onload = function(e) {

                checkStatus();

                document.getElementById( 'gdpr' ).onclick = function(e) {
                    Cookies.set( 'gdpr', '1' );
                    checkStatus();
                }

                document.querySelector( '#disagreeWithGDPR a' ).onclick = function(e) {
                    Cookies.remove( 'gdpr' );
                    checkStatus();
                }

                function checkStatus() {

                    if( typeof Cookies.get( 'gdpr' ) !== 'undefined' ) {
                        document.getElementById( 'hasCompliedWith' ).innerHTML = 'YES';
                        document.getElementById( 'js-gdpr-consent-banner' ).classList.add("hidden");
                        document.querySelector( '#disagreeWithGDPR' ).style.display = 'block';
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById( 'hasCompliedWith' ).innerHTML = 'NO';
                        document.getElementById( 'js-gdpr-consent-banner' ).classList.remove("hidden");
                        document.querySelector( '#disagreeWithGDPR' ).style.display = 'none';
                    }
                }
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I made some changes on my final version, notably to have two buttons, one to manifest the acceptance and another the declinal, instead of just one link to close the banner.

With this, I now register one single Cookie with a boolean-integer value, **1** (one) if the user has accepted the Terms — which was written and left available in a very visible place in the footer — or **0** (zero) if the User declined.

I opted for this format not only to demonstrate the User has a more fine control over the decisions but also to simplify the JS conditions.

But — and here comes the point of this discussion — how to apply this decision to mainly, but not limited to, Google Family Services?

It's so much information scattered across several pages that I honestly got lost, but still I managed to come up with this:

### Google AdSense

```
<script>

    (adsbygoogle=window.adsbygoogle||[]);

    if( typeof cookie !== 'undefined' ) {

        /**
         * @internal
         *
         * Modifying the initialized Google AdSense Object in case the
         * User didn't consent with GDPR
         */
        if( cookie == '0' ) {

            adsbygoogle.requestNonPersonalizedAds = 1;
        }

    } else {

        /**
         * @internal
         *
         * But if the consent Cookie doesn't even exist or if the User is still
         * browsing ignoring the GDPR message in the bottom we'll pause the
         * Ads Request in order to wait for the User to Consent for the first time
         */
        adsbygoogle.pauseAdRequests = 1;
    }

</script>
```

> The **cookie** variable is already initialized in the `<head>` with the Cookie value

After initializing the AdSense variable, I test for the presence of my cookie and if it's not there — which means the GDPR banner will be visible — I make use of 
Google Analytics' `pauseAdRequests`, which, as far as I understood, would not show any ads while the User doesn't consent to the Terms.

If my Cookie does exist, I then test its value and only if **0** (zero), I configure my AdSense with `requestNonPersonalizedAds`. I only know what that means in theory, as I haven't seen it in action yet.

### Google Analytics

Google Analytics was, apparently, easier:

```
if( typeof cookie === 'undefined' || cookie == '0' ) {
    window['ga-disable-UA-XXXXX-Y'] = true;
}
```

All I had to do was test the presence of my Cookie or if its value means the non-acceptance and in that case [disable the tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-opt-out).

Other than that, I also configure it with the [IP Anonymization](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ip-anonymization). Because I'm not sure the impact that not having Users' IP Addresses would cause on my reports, it's there by default, opting-out or not.

Well, that sure was a long topic with all details I could come up with and all code I have so far — except the little difference I mentioned — so I believe now I can have a proper answer for this matter that's bothering me for so much time.

Comment: How can this be unclear?! Goddammit...

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: But it's right there in the text `how to apply this decision mainly, but not limited to, Google Family Services?`

Comment: What's wrong with your solutions so far? This look more like a tutorial than a question tbh.

Comment: I don't know if it's "wrong", I don't know if it's enough. Like I said, I've gathered what I've implemented from several scattered places.